# Why is my CAShapeLayer not animating correctly with the UIView (w/ gif)?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, cashapelayer

[image]

Okay so here's how it goes.

The gray area is a UIView, and masked it with `CAShapeLayer`. I appended two `UIBezierPath` and used the `Even Odd Rule` to remove a portion of that gray area. That is why it shows a line as if it's demonstrating a semi-circle on the left.

The red background is just container view.

Now my problem is that when I animate my `UIView`, it's as if the mask isn't updating correctly with animating `UIView`.

Here's the `UIView` animation part:

```
func didCompleteItem() {
    self.bar.plainProgressBarLeftAnchor?.constant = self.bar.bounds.width * (self.completedItemCount*self.barMeterMultiplier) / self.bar.bounds.width - self.bar.meterCornerRadius
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.bar.layoutIfNeeded()

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Now, here's the `layoutSubviews` part of it, if you need to see how the `CAShapeLayer` was created.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    backgroundColor = GradientColor(.leftToRight, frame: self.bounds, colors: GradientFlatRed())
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.cornerRadius = meterCornerRadius

    createMask()

}

var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
func createMask() {
    let bPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: plainProgressBar.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0))
    let semiCircle = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x, y: plainProgressBar.bounds.origin.y+meterCornerRadius), radius: meterCornerRadius, startAngle: 3 * CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2, clockwise: true)
    shapeLayer.frame = layer.bounds
    bPath.append(semiCircle)
    shapeLayer.path = bPath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
    plainProgressBar.layer.mask = shapeLayer
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't only draw a semi-circle, but a full circle to avoid the issue. Also, maybe in `layoutLayer()` (equivalent of layoutSubView) may help fix it.

Comment: why would `layoutLayer()` solve it? Does it have to do with the life cycle of the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing a stretchable circle and changing the width of the image view that portrays the circle would give you the effect you're after, pretty much without effort and with none of the artifacts you're experiencing:

[image]

Comment: The reason I decrease the gray area instead of making a stretchable red circle is because my red background is a gradient. I could use your approach and add a gradient to the circle but it wouldn't meet my design choice. It'll just look like a gradient circle all the time, even when I stretch it, if you know what I mean. In other words, I want the red background to make it look like it's increasing to a dark red color. That is why the glitch shows a darker red on the right side.

Comment: Then I don't think you've posed the question very clearly. However, masking to a gradient, and changing the shape of the mask, has been very well dealt with on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Still, I don't think that changes my answer significantly. The mask can be a mask view, the mask view can be an image view, and so you can animate the mask in exactly the way I advise.

Comment: Revised my screenshot to show that animating the image-view-as-mask works exactly as you desire. Just tweak the gradient details and you're home free.